# Brackets in equation environment are being ignored

Tags: brackets

My problem is that all parentheses within an equation environment are ignored in my resulting PDFs. I have no idea where the issue is but it must have something to do with the packages I'm loading.

Please find a MWE below:

```
\documentclass[
    bibliography=totoc, % Add the bibliography to the TOC
    listof=totoc,      % Add the "List of *" to the TOC
    %final              % Set document status as FINAL
    %draft              % Set document status as DRAFT: Faster, skips some stuff (e.g. referencing)
]{scrbook}              % scrbook defaults: a4paper, twoside, openright, 11pt

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Requirements

% Color
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

% TIKZ
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{external} % Externalizes Tikz graphics - speeds up compilation if unchanged.
    \usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows,fit,automata}

% If-Then statements
\usepackage{ifthen}
    \newboolean{publicationversion}
    \newboolean{DRing}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Page Geometry Layout
\usepackage[
        a4paper,
        top=35mm,
        bottom=40mm,
        inner=35mm,
        outer=40mm,
        bindingoffset=5mm,
        marginparsep=5mm,
        marginparwidth=40mm,
        %showframe  % Can be enabled to debug the page geometry
    ]{geometry}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Header & Footer

\usepackage[
        headsepline,
        footsepline,
        draft=false     % Draft mode adds "ruler" instead of header/footer, we never want that!
    ]{scrlayer-scrpage}

% Style
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\chapapp~\thechapter:\enskip}% Put "chapter" oder "appendix" in front of the chapter number in running head
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\headmark}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\automark*[section]{}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Fancy Chapter Titles (rectangle, large number,.. )

\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}

% Modify `Lenny` style to also cover Abstract/Appendicies/...
\makeatletter
\newlength{\backskip}
\renewcommand{\DOTIS}[1]{%
    \settowidth{\px}{\CNV{#1}}
    \addtolength{\px}{2pt}
    \settoheight{\py}{\CNV{#1}}
    \addtolength{\py}{1pt}
    \settowidth{\mylen}{\CNV{#1}}
    \addtolength{\mylen}{1pt}
    \settoheight{\pyy}{\CNoV\thechapter}
    \addtolength{\pyy}{-2pt}
    \setlength{\myhi}{\pyy}
    \addtolength{\myhi}{-1\py}
    \par
    \parbox[b]{\textwidth}{%
    \rule[\py]{\RW}{\myhi}%
    \hskip -\RW%
    \rule[\pyy]{\px}{\RW}%TOP1
    \hskip -\px%
    \raggedright%
    \CNV{#1}%
    \hskip1pt%
    \mghrulefill{\RW}%
    \rule{\RW}{\pyy}\par\nobreak%
    \vskip -\baselineskip%
    \vskip -\pyy%
    \hskip \mylen%
    \mghrulefill{\RW}\par\nobreak%
    \vskip \pyy}%
    \vskip 20\p@}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Captions for Figures
\usepackage[
        font={small},
        labelfont={small,bf}
    ]{caption}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% TOC: Mini TOC, e.g., at beginning of chapters.
\usepackage{etoc}
\newcommand{\chaptertoc}[1][Contents]{%
    \etocsettocstyle{\addsec*{#1\\[-12pt]\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}}{}%
    \etocsetnexttocdepth{2}%
    \localtableofcontents%
    \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}%
    \bigskip{}%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
% PDF Links 
\usepackage[
        bookmarksdepth=3,   % bookmark levels in the PDF.
        bookmarksnumbered   % Show section numbering in bookmark
    ]{hyperref}
    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% ToDo Notes
\usepackage[
        colorinlistoftodos,
        textsize=footnotesize,
        obeyDraft
    ]{todonotes}

% ToDo style
\makeatletter
    \tikzstyle{notestyleraw}=[
      draw=\@todonotes@currentbordercolor,
      fill=\@todonotes@currentbackgroundcolor,
      line width=0.5pt,
      text width=\@todonotes@textwidth-1.6ex-1pt,
      inner sep=0.8ex
    ]
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Glossary / Acronym List
\usepackage[nomain,
        acronym,
        shortcuts,      % short commands: \Ac,\ac,\Acl,\acl,\Acs,\acs,\Acf,\acf
        nopostdot,      % no dot at end of each entry
        nogroupskip     % no spacing between groups (same first letter)
    ]{glossaries}

% Glossary style
\newglossarystyle{mylong}{%
    \setglossarystyle{long}%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}{\begin{longtable}[l]{lp{.8\linewidth}}}{\end{longtable}}%
    \renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{##1}}%
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
        \Glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2\tabularnewline
    }%
}

% Additional commands that are safe to use in headlines & captions (Hyperref/TOC context).
\newcommand{\AcfHeadline}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\Glsentryfull{#1}}{#1}}
\newcommand{\acfHeadline}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\glsentryfull{#1}}{#1}}
\newcommand{\AclHeadline}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\Glsentrylong{#1}}{#1}}
\newcommand{\aclHeadline}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\glsentrylong{#1}}{#1}}
\newcommand{\acsHeadline}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\glsentryshort{#1}}{#1}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Bibliography / Citing
\usepackage[
        backend=biber,
        style=numeric, %alphabetic,
        sorting=none,
        minnames=4,
        maxnames=10
    ]{biblatex}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Content Stuff
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{framed}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Math stuff
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stmaryrd} % e.g. llbracket
\usepackage{MnSymbol} % e.g. llangle

% Theorem, Definition, etc. environments
\usepackage[framed]{ntheorem}
    % Definition
        \makeatletter
        \newtheoremstyle{angularbreak}
            {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}%
            {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\ \textlangle\,##3\,\textrangle\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}
        \makeatother
        \theoremstyle{angularbreak}
        \theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\clubsuit}}
        \newframedtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]
    % Lemma
        \theoremstyle{plain}
        \theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\heartsuit}}
        %\theoremseparator{:}
        \newframedtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[chapter]
    % Theorem
        \theoremstyle{plain}
        \theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}\theorembodyfont{\slshape}
        \theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\diamondsuit}}
        %\theoremseparator{:}
        \newframedtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
    % Proof
        \theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
        \theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
        \theoremsymbol{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}
        \theoremseparator{}
        \newtheorem{proof}{Proof}[chapter]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Code stuff
\usepackage{listings}           % Code Listings
    \usepackage{lstautogobble}  % Automatically ignore white-space based on first line.

\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Set PDF attributes %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle = {\@title},
    pdfauthor= {\@author}
}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
% -MAIN DOCUMENT------------------------------------------------------------- %
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Custom packages
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{chronosys}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[super]{nth}

% Custom packages that need to be loaded to suppress warnings
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
Test 1
\begin{equation}
A(x) = 5
\end{equation}
Test 2

\end{document}
```

The output can be seen below:
[image: Expected output]

I expect the parentheses to be present in the output as well.

Comment: You should be aware of the fact that `\usepackage{MnSymbol}` changes ***all*** math symbols using glyphs that clash with Latin Modern. The issue is due to `\usepackage{lmodern}` coming after `\usepackage{MnSymbol}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the issue indeed. :) If you had written an answer, I could have accepted and upvoted it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was a font issue that was solved in the comments.